# Opus encoder with channels=8 and mpegtsmux is not working

Tags: gstreamer

**Pipeline:** gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=4 num-buffers=3600 ! video/x-raw, width=3840, height=2160, format=NV12, framerate=60/1 ! omxh265enc gop-mode=basic gop-length=60 b-frames=0 target-bitrate=60000 max-picture-size=1100 num-slices=8 control-rate=constant prefetch-buffer=true low-bandwidth=false filler-data=true cpb-size=1000 initial-delay=500 ! video/x-h265, profile=main, alignment=au ! queue max-size-bytes=0 ! mux. alsasrc device=hw:1,1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, rate=48000, **channels=8,** layout=interleaved ! queue ! opusenc ! opusparse ! queue max-size-bytes=0 ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location="/run/test.ts"

Above pipeline is not working, However if channels=7 it is working.

Below are GST_DEBUG=3 logs of the pipeline:

```
0:00:00.150296457 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e15a80 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m                v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4382:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2src0:src>[00m Failed to probe pixel aspect ratio with VIDIOC_CROPCAP: Invalid argument
0:00:00.150388856 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e159e0 [32;01mFIXME  [00m [00;04m             default gstutils.c:3980:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<alsasrc0:src>[00m Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:00.151335541 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e15a80 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m                v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:3205:gst_v4l2_object_save_format:<v4l2src0>[00m format NV16_10LE32 has a pstride of 0, cannot compute padded with
0:00:00.153998227 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e15a80 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m         omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:833:gst_omx_video_enc_set_transfer_characteristics:<omxh265enc-omxh265enc0>[00m Provided transfer characteristics 11 (bt2020) are not supported
0:00:00.154525200 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e15a80 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m                v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:3205:gst_v4l2_object_save_format:<v4l2src0>[00m format NV16_10LE32 has a pstride of 0, cannot compute padded with
0:00:00.173773953 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e159e0 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m                alsa pcm_hw.c:1359:snd_pcm_hw_get_chmap:[00m alsalib error: Cannot read Channel Map ctl
: No such file or directory
0:00:00.181625698 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e15b20 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m     audio-resampler audio-resampler.c:274:convert_taps_gint16_c:[00m can't find exact taps
0:00:00.340288901 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e15ad0 [32;01mFIXME  [00m [00m           mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:748:mpegtsmux_create_stream:<mux:sink_66>[00m Opus channel mapping not handled
0:00:00.340399272 [336m14963[00m   0x5569e15ad0 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m           mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1010:mpegtsmux_create_streams:<mux>[00m error: Could not create handler for stream
0:00:00.360425263 [336m14963[00m   0x7f94003800 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m            omxvideo gstomxvideo.c:223:gst_omx_video_find_nearest_frame:<omxh265enc-omxh265enc0>[00m Difference between ts (0:00:00.000000000) and frame 1 (0:00:00.101057829) seems too high (0:00:00.101057829)
0:00:00.360559206 [336m14963[00m   0x7f94003800 [33;01mWARN   [00m [00m            omxvideo gstomxvideo.c:223:gst_omx_video_find_nearest_frame:<omxh265enc-omxh265enc0>[00m Difference between ts (0:00:00.000000000) and frame 1 (0:00:00.101057829) seems too high (0:00:00.101057829)
```

It seems that there is some issue with **mpegtsmux - Opus channel mapping not handled**, so guessing if we provide **channel-positions** using rawaudioparse then it might fix the issue. But, **channel-positions** is expecting GValueArray type input, so how can we provide that I am not sure.

Also not sure, if any other particular fix required in pipeline.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  You should ask about the problem or task that you face instead of asking about a proposed solution.  Please explain what you want to do.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: Updated the description with proper explanation.

Comment: I put some debug prints in the mpegtsmux codec, where I got:

mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:705:mpegtsmux_create_stream:<mux:sink_66> channels=8, mapping family=1, stream count=5, coupled-count=3, **channel-mapping = [0, 6, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 7]**

expected channel-mapping in mpegtsmux = {0, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, or { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

see lines 711 to 750
 https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/054dc5282de069191f0d599631803a8eda03e12a/gst/mpegtsmux/mpegtsmux.c

what could be possible solutions in pipeline, rather than updating channel mapping array in mpegtsmux.c ?

Comment: There are GStreamer API to reorder channel map

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/audio/gstaudiochannels.html?gi-language=c#gst_audio_get_channel_reorder_map

But, How can we manage this with GStreamer pipeline ?